# Parsing JSON array in android

Tags: android, json

I have a json response in the format `[{id:1, name:a}{id:2, name:b}]`. I want to put name values(a, b..) in the spinner. If I select an item in the spinner lets say 'a' I need to get the id value that is 1. How can I do that? Please help me on this. Examples will be helpful.

```
    createworkorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String url = "http://192.168.10.60:8095/tmanager/city?";
                url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entityres = response.getEntity();
                isX = entityres.getContent();
                response_string = Utils1.getResponse(isX);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                System.out.println("Error in http connection "
                        + e.toString());
            }

            allCities = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                cityArray = new JSONArray(response_string);

                for (int i = 0; i < cityArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = cityArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Iterator<String> it = obj.keys();

                    String str = it.next().toString().trim();
                    Log.v("str is", str);

                    allCities.add(str);

                    intent = new Intent(CreateOpenWO.this,
                            CreateWorkOrder.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON", "There was an error parsing the JSON", e);
            }

        }
    });`enter code here`
```

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: make an arraylist and add elements(a,b,c, etc.) to it by parsing the JSONArray using a for loop. Then use that Arraylist to populate the spinner.

Comment: Have a look at Gson. It'll make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a usable spinner with your data like this

```
Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);

ArrayList<String> yourSpinnerData = new ArrayList<String>();
String yourJsonString = "[{id:1, name:'a'},{id:2, name:'b'}]";

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
        int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        // do things with the values you pull here!
        yourSpinnerData.add(name);
    }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Use spinner data
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourSpinnerData);
yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, in future you should provide code snippits, it makes questions a lot easier to answer! :)

Comment: I completely understand what actually you are referring to. But using above code I'm not able to get the id corresponding to the name selected. Let me paste the code snippet what I have currently

Comment: @user3782869 Yeah, just paste your code here and I can see if I can help you with your problem!

You see, if you want to get the id ASWELL as the name, you may have to create a custom object with an id property and a name property. You then have to create an adapter which will handle that object and set the adapter of the spinner to that adapter. It's similar to a listview if you've created an adapter for one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming JSON format:

```
String s = "[{id:1, name:'a'}, {id:2, name:'b'}]";
        JSONArray ja;
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray (s);
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length (); i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = ja.getJSONObject (i);
                jObj.get ("memberName");
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem , I solved like this. 
First , create Data Transfer Object like this,(Its simply a getter and setter).

```
public class NameCodeDTO {
private  int id;
private int code;
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then create a custom spinner adapter like this,

```
public class SpinnerNameCodeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NameCodeDTO> {

private Context mContext;
private List<NameCodeDTO> nameCodeDTOList;
private int layoutId;
LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public SpinnerNameCodeAdapter(Context mContext, int resource,List<NameCodeDTO>nameCodeDTOList) {
    super(mContext, resource,nameCodeDTOList);
    this.mContext=mContext;
    this.layoutId=resource;
    this.nameCodeDTOList=nameCodeDTOList;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nameCodeDTOList.size();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public NameCodeDTO getItem(int position) {
    return nameCodeDTOList.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}


@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  return getCustomView(position,view,parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

    if(view==null){
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null, false);

        holder.spinnerText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_simple_spinner);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    NameCodeDTO nameCodeDTO=nameCodeDTOList.get(position);
    holder.spinnerText.setText(nameCodeDTO.getName());
    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView spinnerText;
}
```

}

Assuming that json string is available in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner mySpinner;
List<NameCodeDTO> nameIdList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    mySpinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    //do json parsing here for json structure [{id:1, name:a}{id:2, name:b}]

    nameIdList=new Array<NamecodeDTO>();

    JSONArray ja;


    try {
        ja = new JSONArray (s);
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length (); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = ja.getJSONObject (i);
            String name=jObj.getString("name");
            String id=jObj.getString("id");

            NameCodeDTO nameCodeDTO= new NameCodeDTO();
            nameCodeDTO.setName(name);
            nameCodeDTO.setId(id);

            nameIdList.add(NameCodeDTO);

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //you_spinner_text.xml layout has TextView with id is tv_spinner_simple

    mySpinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerNameCodeAdapter (this,R.id.your_spinner_text, nameIdList));

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {



      NameCodeDTO nameId=(NameCodeDTO)(adapterView).getItemAtPosition(position);
   // this gives the desired answer
        Log.i("spinner name::",nameId.getName());
        Log.i("spinner id::", nameId.getId());

 }
}
```

Hope this helps you.